# How to convert html data to PDF in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I want to convert html to pdf dynamically in objective c.
what is the best way to convert it, so that it maintains its look same as html.
Thanks in advance.

Prasad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html) will help you to create a PDF file which shows your web content. Read through the documentation and create your own solution or just follow the tutorials I found:

- [Convert Html or UIWebView to pdf in iPhone or iPad](http://www.ioslearner.com/convert-html-uiwebview-pdf-iphone-ipad/)
- [Making a PDF from a UIWebView](http://coderchrismills.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/making-a-pdf-from-a-uiwebview/)

Comment: Thank you moosgummi for sharing this great links, the only problem with the generated pdf is, if you want copy some text out of pdf to use somewhere else, it is not possible. In case of Haru lib you can copy text from pdf.

Comment: That's true … The main problem is that `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile` generates images and not "real text" inside the PDF, so you have to deal with that first.

Comment: hi I have got one requirement that i have to load one html file and that html file will have text fields, labels, check box buttons etc. I have to get the data whatever user will enter and then i have to convert it into pdf with user enter data.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this Haru open source library, it is quite simple and useful for creating pdfs http://libharu.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: using libharu is it possible to convert html to pdf ? because  the sample i got from github just adds the text to pdf ? can u provide me any links to convert html to pdf using libharu ?

Comment: actually it doesn't convert HTML to PDF directly we have to write text line by line and need to set its look like website manually.At that time i have used libharu which is almost 2 years ago, so currently i dont know is it a good choice to go with it.

Comment: Is there any sample , you used ?

Comment: hi I have got one requirement that i have to load one html file and that html file will have text fields, labels, check box buttons etc. I have to get the data whatever user will enter and then i have to convert it into pdf with user enter data.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is a programming language, it doesn’t know anything about HTML or PDF per se. How to do this depends on the framework you’re using. I’m assuming here you’re using Cocoa on OS X.

There you can load your HTML into a [`WebView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001903) provided by WebKit and then use the `NSView` method [`dataWithPDFInsideRect:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/dataWithPDFInsideRect:) to render it as PDF. I haven’t tested this, but maybe you’ll have to add the web view to a window before you can query the PDF data.

Comment: Am I right in that this method is not available in the iPhone SDK?  If so, does anyone know how I can do this on the iPhone?