# iOS, share webView content (long text or .pdf) via twitter and Facebook

Tags: ios, pdf, webview, social-framework

Hello fellow developers,

I have some html loaded into a webview. I need to share its contents with twitter and Facebook, hence need to understand the following:

1. Is there a way to share long text to twitter? If that's not supported natively, maybe you are aware of some service that would accept some text and give me a link for that
2. I'm able to generate a .pdf from webview (following some article from this question [How to convert html data to PDF in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750982/how-to-convert-html-data-to-pdf-in-objective-c)) Are you aware of some service with iOS SDK that would accept a .pdf file and give me a link for that ? Having that you could simply share link via twitter.

I've spent some time googling both of those and at the moment the only idea is using dropbox, which kinda solves the case but provides not the best user experience since one would need to log-in to dropbox to enable the share functionality.

Looking forward to hear your thoughts.

--Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend setting up a basic PHP service on your website (if you have one) to where you can upload the .PDF and then feed the returning link to an iOS API such as bit.ly's.

Their API will return a shortened link to the .PDF on your website and you can also track click counts with bit.ly

http://github.com/bitly/bitly_ios_sdk